# Got an error when try to print stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString method

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nslog

When i try to print this string i got bad access error:

```
NSString *myPath = [myPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/Users/Me/Library/iPhone/4.2/MyApp/Documents/Photos/pic1.png" 
                                                         withString:@"/Users/John/Library/iPhone/5/MyApp/Documents/Photos/picture.png"];

    NSLog(@"%@", myPath);
```

Why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you are calling the method stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString on a variable (myPath) that has not been instantiated. You need to call that method on an instance of the NSString class that already contains the string you are replacing text in.

Comment: Thank you very much for replay, i tried to figure it out without success. now there is no error but the output doesn't show up. i add     NSString *myPath = [[NSString alloc] init];

Answer (score 1):

When you call a method you call it on the `receiver`. Therefore you are calling `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` on `myPath`.

You are assigning the value of the method into

```
NSString *myPath
```

which makes me assume that the `myPath` in

```
[myPath ....
```

is not actually set to anything. (potentially pointing to garbage)

What you want is something like this

```
NSString *startString = @"hello";

//                            Receiver         Message
//                               |                |
//                               v                v
NSString *replacedString = [startString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"hello" 
                                                                  withString:@"bye bye"];

NSLog(@"Results in => %@", replacedString);

// Output
2011-12-11 20:50:01.964 Untitled 2[779:707] Results in => bye bye
```

In your above comment you tried `NSString *myPath = [[NSString alloc] init];` this would create an empty string. An empty string does not contain any occurrences of `@"/Users/Me/Library/iPhone/4.2/MyApp/Documents/Photos/pic1.png"` therefore it can't replace them.

Comment: @EladHadad if this worked for you then you should accept this answer by clicking the checkbox next to the answer (it will turn green) so that he gets credit for helping you.